# Tensorflow: No module named contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist

Tags: python, module, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
```

I tried executing the above and I am getting the below error:

```
ImportError: No module named contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist
```

I did `sudo pip show tensorflow`.
The location showed `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

So, I appended /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages to sys.path. But still getting the same error.

I'm not able to use anything from contrib.

`training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int)`

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'contrib'`

Could somebody please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you update TensorFlow to 0.9 or 0.10 if you haven't?

Comment: I installed Tesnorflow 0.10. I uninstalled the current version of tensorflow and installed using condo. Now I'm able to use the modules without any problem.

Comment: contrib was only added in 0.8 I think

Answer (score 0):

The [TF 0.7 MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) suggests this snippet for loading data

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

Comment: I ran `from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`, still getting the same error. `ImportError: No module named examples.tutorials.mnist`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the version of tensorflow you are using... I had the same issue with TF 1.15 downgraded to TF 1.12 and this fixed the problem

from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.